# Applying function to dictionary values not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, toolz

I am attempting to apply  the `gower_matrix` function from the `gower` package to the values of a dictionary using this chunk of code:

```
import gower
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain, combinations
from pydataset import data
from toolz.dicttoolz import valmap

cars = data('mtcars')
vnames=cars.columns
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(1,len(s)+1))

combos=list(powerset(vnames))
combos=list(map(list, list(powerset(vnames))))
combo_dicts = {}
keys = range(len(combos))

for i in keys:
        combo_dicts[i] = cars[combos[i]]
        
gower_dicts = valmap(gower.gower_matrix, combo_dicts)
```

but I am receiving the following error

```
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' output (typecode 'd') 
could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'q') 
according to the casting rule ''same_kind''
```

Applying it to a particular dictionary item works

```
gower.gower_matrix(combo_dicts[100])


array([[0.        , 0.02173357, 0.19395797, ..., 0.12646227, 0.35655078,
        0.11454861],
       [0.02173357, 0.        , 0.21569154, ..., 0.12262693, 0.3348172 ,
        0.10900868],
       [0.19395797, 0.21569154, 0.        , ..., 0.32042024, 0.55050874,
        0.10668287],
       ...,
       [0.12646227, 0.12262693, 0.32042024, ..., 0.        , 0.23008852,
        0.21544196],
       [0.35655078, 0.3348172 , 0.55050874, ..., 0.23008852, 0.        ,
        0.44382587],
       [0.11454861, 0.10900868, 0.10668287, ..., 0.21544196, 0.44382587,
        0.        ]], dtype=float32)
```

Any idea on the issue?

Comment: Does it work if you manually iterate over the values? Maybe element 100 is okay but some others are not. But if your keys come from a numeric `range`, why not just build a list instead?

Comment: I've never heard of a gower matrix previously. Are you using [this thing](https://www.thinkdatascience.com/post/2019-12-16-introducing-python-package-gower/) perhaps?

Comment: Yes, forgot to add the package  the function comes from.

Comment: how would I build the list? I just need a way to access by name  or some other way each of the data frames  because eventually they will be used to build separate models

Comment: Uhh... `combo_list = [cars[combo] for combo in combos]`?

Comment: Similarly, you could use a comprehension instead of the `map` trick: `combos = [list(name) for name in powerset(vnames)]`.

Comment: Thanks! new to python, I am converting code from another language appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a web search for `ufunc 'true_divide' output`, it [appears](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6464) that the error occurs (not a Numpy bug, but behaviour that changed several years ago) when attempting to divide an array of integer values through by a floating-point value. It appears to be an unspecified requirement of the `gower` package that you pass in floating-point values. So convert the `cars` data first. My guess is that you have some columns that contain floating-point values and some that contain integers; the test element of `combo_dicts` works fine because it happens to have been produced only from floating-point columns.